# Generating Google Maps markers using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to do a very simple task: add some markers in a Google Map using a list of addresses from an array.

I have been thinking about generating the Google Maps JavaScript API code using ruby (printf) but this does not seem like a very clean and beautiful solution...

I have read about YM4R for Ruby on Rails... my project is pretty simple and I have never worked with Ruby on Rails... I have also never used JQuery... but I am very willing to learn to use this tools :)

What do you think will be the best approach to generating the markers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fyi, I've just released a new version of gmaps4rails.

It's based on Rails 3 and uses Google maps API V3:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 1):

YM4R is a good choice. In the end you'll just need a few lines of code to get this done, as [outlined in the tutorial](http://ym4r.rubyforge.org/tutorial_traffic.html). Even given your background, you should be able to follow the examples and get things working.

We also use the Geokit plugin, which is a little more complicated because of the set-up. But if you already have the lat/lon, you're good.